# Can I show an index number when raising a ValueError?

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror, raise

I want to check the input format for a given function with a list of lists as input. I have used the code below to indicate at which index the input file has the wrong format:

```
for i, doc in enumerate(input_file):
    if not isinstance(doc,list):
        raise ValueError("The element of input_file at index ' + str(i) + ' is not a list")
```

However, the output of this code (with wrong input) is:

```
ValueError: The element of input_file at index ' + str(i) + ' is not a list
```

So, it does not convert `str(i)` to an actual number. Is it possible to get a number there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax was wrong. You have not concatenated the numbers.
The code
`raise ValueError("The element of input_file at index ' + str(i) + ' is not a list")` basically considers `'+ str(i) +'` as a string only.

Try this:

```
raise ValueError(f"The element of input_file at index '{i}' is not a list")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double (") instead of single quotes (')

Comment: That was silly of me, thanks